Moving coil galvanometer (coil angle)

Radial Field: According to the above formula, the strength of the current is not proportional to the deflection $\phi$. Hence, the current cannot be read directly. To remove this difficulty, it is necessary that in every position of the coil, the plane of the coil be parallel to the magnetic field so that the deflecting torque always be $NIAB$. It is for this purpose that the coil is suspended between cylindrically-cut pole-pieces and a soft-iron core is placed within the coil without touching it anywhere. Then the magnetic lines of forces are no longer parallel but their distribution becomes as shown in Fig. 4. Due to the large permeability of soft-iron, more lines of force pass through the core and thus makes the magnetic field strong. Such a magnetic field is called 'radial field'. In this field, in every position the plane of the coil remains parallel to the lines of force, that is, in every position $\boldsymbol{\theta=90^{\mathrm{o}}}$. Hence, the deflecting torque on the field is always $NIAB$...

I am new to this topic. The two emphasized sections seem somewhat confusing.
I understand that taking a radial approach will eliminate the inverse proportionality of $\sin\theta$ in the value of $I$.
Could anyone please help me understand the relation between parallel and perpendicular here?

I've transcribed your text, please avoid posting pictures of text next time.

@Amit apologies. Not very familiar with this. Thank you for your help.
